# Auth0 Laravel get JWT token

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-8, auth0

I'm using Auth0 as my OAuth provider, which works really well. The whole thing runs in my Laravel backend and it properly redirects and comes back with authentication. The problem however is that the I can't find the function to retrieve the JWT token. I know I can just do a curl request with the proper data, but it seems illogical to build one up when all the url data is already available in `Auth0\Login\Auth0Service`. So I'm either not looking in the right direction or it's not there.

Question is: Is there a function for easy retrieval of the jwt token provided in the Auth0 package for Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your example then I will see what the specific problem in your code,

Generally, you can access to the token.

Next example has a bearer token and you can access `$request->bearerToken()`

```
 /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $auth0 = app()->make('auth0');

    $accessToken = $request->bearerToken();
    try {
      $tokenInfo = $auth0->decodeJWT($accessToken);
      $user = $this->userRepository->getUserByDecodedJWT($tokenInfo);
      if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(["message" => "Unauthorized user"], 401);
      }

    } catch (InvalidTokenException $e) {
      return response()->json(["message" => $e->getMessage()], 401);
    } catch (CoreException $e) {
      return response()->json(["message" => $e->getMessage()], 401);
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
```

Comment: You are showing the API connection. With that there is a bearer token in the request body. I'm using the webapp version: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel#configure-auth0

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to my question was in the config file `'persist_id_token' => true,`. That gave me the jwt token. But in the end that was not total solution. The user data was not included because of two problems. The first was the scope; it did not have profile. The second problem was that a lot of data was out of scope. So we made custom scopes to solve that.

In the end it seemed I did not know about the scope/claims as defined by OIDC. It can be found here: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-token-claims